# Make Zurb Fondation's TwentyTwenty plugin work with HTML content instead of Images

Tags: jquery, html, zurb-foundation

Is there an option to use Zurb Foundation [TwentyTwenty plugin](http://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty) with HTML content instead of just images?

This one works as expected:

```
<div class="large-4 columns">
    <div class="twentytwenty-container">
      <img src="img/3_1.jpg" />
      <img src="img/3_2.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

But this one does not:

```
<div class="large-4 columns">
    <div class="twentytwenty-container">
      <div style="width:300px; height:300px;>1</div>
      <div style="width:300px; height:300px;>2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Here's the source doe on GitHub](https://github.com/zurb/twentytwenty).

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Z3hd/)

Comment: What doesn't work? Are your div absolutely positioned?

Comment: Just had a quick look at the source and it has a lot of `container.find('img')` and the like. This needs to be changed to something else. E.g if the container is `.twentytwenty-container` `container.children()` ought to do it. However there is some calculations on width and height on the image, these needs some modifications (`calcOffset()` and `adjustContainer()` I would guess) so it calculates based on the div instead of image.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin, No. When I do apply position absolute, everything dissapears from the page

Comment: @JohnKlakegg changing to DIV instead of IMG in various places gives me the handle to appear right. Yet, the content appears one below the other.

Comment: I am also making changes to the CSS to reflect on the DIV instead of the IMG

Comment: @JohnKlakegg The width and height are right and works good as-is for the DIVs (I'ved used span actually because the script put other DIV elements inside and I don't want those to be overriden) . at the end I get the same results, with the second DIV text under the first DIV, so didn't solve it yet.

Comment: Here's the fiddle (demo): http://jsfiddle.net/8Z3hd/

Comment: I think I've got it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/8Z3hd/1/ -- it shows the two because the layers are transparent obviously, so if I use a background color to the DIV it will look as intended.

Comment: Ah alright, you are getting close to a solution there, just minor css changes left it seems.